# Passing a return char* from C++ to C# with DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, return, dllimport

I am a newbie on both C# WPF and C++.

Recently, I got an external .dll, which returns a `char*`, and I want to receive the return value in C# by using `DllImport`. Then, using `str.Split(';')` to separate the characters. To the purpose, I created a button to show the first character in the string I split on a label when I click the button.

Therefore, I use an `IntPtr` to receive a `char*`, which is from C++ .dll, and call `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` to turn it into a string. However, when I execute the code, it sometimes works but sometimes crushes. Then error code always shows

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC06839269 (ntdll.dll) in UITest.exe: 0xC0000374: heap corruption  (parameters: 0x00007FFC068A27F0).
```

I thought my code is reasonable and I couldn't find root causes. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

The below shows the content in .dll and also the code I used in C#.

- C++ code in Dlltest.h:

  ```
  #define DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
  char* getRbtData = nullptr;
  DLL_EXPORT char* func_getRbtData();
  ```
- C++ code in Dlltest.cpp:

  ```
  char* func_getRbtData()
  {
     getRbtData = new char(128);
     memset(getRbtData, 0, strlen(getRbtData));
     char* _getRbtData = "1.0;23.0;55.0;91.0;594.0;";
     memcpy(getRbtData, _getRbtData, strlen(_getRbtData));
     return getRbtData;
  };
  ```
- C# code in UITest.xaml.cs:

  ```
  [DllImport("DllTest.dll",EntryPoint = "func_getRbtData", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

  public static extern IntPtr func_getRbtData();

  string[] words;
  private void btn_test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      IntPtr intptr = func_getRbtData();
      string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(intptr);
      words = str.Split(';');
      lb_content.Content = words[1];
  }
  ```

Comment: Irrespective to whether it works, a global `char*` variable used as a shared buffer to return strings is a very weird solution. If you have to allocate the memory on the C++ side, use `LocalAlloc` or `AllocCoTaskMem` and deallocate the returned pointer using the respective methods of `Marshal`.

Comment: [... or StringBuffer ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198213/calling-c-function-with-lpstr-return-value-from-c-sharp/53201035#53201035)

Comment: `char *`.  You shouldn't be returning a `char *`, unless it is the same pointer provided to you by the client.  What most exported functions do is have the client (your C# code) create the buffer, and all the C++ code does is fill the buffer.  FYI, this is how all exported Windows API functions work when dealing with character data.  The exported function shouldn't be in the business of allocating memory unless there is a *documented way* on the client side to deallocate that memory.  For example, is there a "func_freeRbtData" that is exported?  If not, you've created a potential memory leak.

Comment: not mention that you may just put reference to structure with double fields or double array and fill it on C++ side because your "words" looks like doubles

Comment: Shocking the memory is assigned inside the DLL and then poi ter sent out. Bit strange. Ideally memory ownership should be with function caller.

Comment: Even if you manage to allocate 128 characters, the first call to memset is wrong. Ask yourself how strlen works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

On the C++ side, your DLL function is implemented all wrong:

- `getRbtData = new char(128);`

  You are allocating a *single* `char` whose value is 128, not an *array* of 128 `char`s. You need to use `new char[128]` instead for that.
- `memset(getRbtData, 0, strlen(getRbtData));`

  `getRbtData` is not a pointer to a null-terminated string, so `strlen(getRbtData)` is *undefined behavior*. It reads into surrounding memory while calculating the length until it finds a random 0x00 byte in memory.

  And then the subsequent `memset()` into `getRbtData` will overwrite that surrounding memory. If it doesn't just crash outright.
- `char* _getRbtData = "1.0;23.0;55.0;91.0;594.0;";`

  Prior to C++11, this assignment is OK but discouraged. In C++11 and later, this assignment is actually illegal and won't compile.

  String literals are read-only data, so you need to use `const char` instead of `char` in your pointer type. You should do that even in older compilers.
- `memcpy(getRbtData, _getRbtData, strlen(_getRbtData));`

  `strlen(_getRbtData)` is OK since `_getRbtData` is a pointer to a null-terminated string.

  However, since `getRbtData` is not allocated with enough memory to receive all of the copied `char`s, `memcpy()` into `getRbtData` is also *undefined behavior* and will trash memory, if not crash outright.
- `return getRbtData;`

  This is OK to pass the pointer to C#.

  However, since the memory is being allocated with `new` (better, `new[]`), it needs to be freed with `delete` (`delete[]`), which you are not doing. So you are leaking the memory.

  `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` on the C# side will not (and cannot) free `new`'ed memory for you. So your C# code will need to pass the pointer back to the DLL so it can `delete` the memory properly.

  Otherwise, you will need to allocate the memory using the Win32 API `LocalAlloc()` or `CoTaskMemAlloc()` function so that the `Marshal` class can be used on the C# side to free the memory directly without passing it back to the DLL at all.

On the C# side, you are using the wrong calling convention on your `DllImport` statement. The default is `StdCall` for compatibility with most Win32 API functions. But your DLL function is not specifying any calling convention at all. Most C/C++ compilers will default to `__cdecl` unless configured differently.

With that said, try this instead:

Dlltest.h

```cpp
#define DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DLL_EXPORT char* func_getRbtData();
DLL_EXPORT void func_freeRbtData(char*);
```

Dlltest.cpp

```cpp
char* func_getRbtData()
{
    const char* _getRbtData = "1.0;23.0;55.0;91.0;594.0;";
    int len = strlen(_getRbtData);
    char *getRbtData = new char[len+1];
    // alternatively:
    /*
    char *getRbtData = (char*) LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, len+1);
    if (!getRbtData) return NULL;
    */
    memcpy(getRbtData, _getRbtData, len+1);
    return getRbtData;
}

void func_freeRbtData(char *p)
{
    delete[] p;
    // alternatively:
    // LocalFree((HLOCAL)p);
}
```

UITest.xaml.cs

```cs
[DllImport("DllTest.dll", EntryPoint = "func_getRbtData", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr func_getRbtData();

[DllImport("DllTest.dll", EntryPoint = "func_freeRbtData", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void func_freeRbtData(IntPtr p);

string[] words;
private void btn_test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr intptr = func_getRbtData();
    string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(intptr);
    func_freeRbtData(intptr);
    // alternatively:
    // Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intptr);
    words = str.Split(';');
    lb_content.Content = words[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help and for providing such a detail solution!!! I found the mistakes I made and then corrected it. It works well!.

I am also curious about the alternative, so I tried the one you suggested in C#, which is `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intptr);` , to release the memory produced in C++. However, it didn't work. Instead, it showed the below error
`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC06839269 (ntdll.dll) in UITest.exe: 
0xC0000374: heap corruption  (parameters: 0x00007FFC068A27F0).`

Comment: Do you know the reason why?

Comment: That code does work, but of course you need to allocate the memory with `LocalAlloc` in the C++ code, as Remy explained

Answer (score 0):

`new char(128)` returns a pointer to one character, with initial value 128.

I could tell you how to allocate 128 characters, but the chief problem with that is that you can't clean it up so that's not a useful answer. Check the existing questions about returning a string to C#.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! After studying articles, and I found where the mistakes are!